# How to render HTML text in pdftron?

Tags: c#, html, css, pdftron

In C# project I use pdftron for create pdf reports. But I need to add html text with css for render. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the formats that are supported in PDFTron

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/basics/open/url/

I suggest you to convert your html code to Base64 and render it in PDFTron.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PDFTron SDK to convert HTML to PDF using our HTML2PDF module, and use our SDK to modify that resulting PDF and add it to your report.

Please see the HTML2PDF sample from the link below for more information:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/#html2pdf